# how to check if the transition name is valid in jquery.mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, transition

I have a javascript method which accepts the transition name as a parameter and passes it to jquery.mobile for changing page:

```
$.mobile.changePage(renderedPage, { transition: transition, reverse: reverse });
```

Now I need to check if the transition name passed to my method is a valid transition. (this is because invalid transition name will cause a break in .changePage() method)

I browsed the source code of jquery.mobile but could not find a collection that contains all transition names or transition handlers.

Anybody has a trick to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery mobile, there are only six transitions available. you could just make sure that the given transition is in the array of available transitions.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html

```
var transitionArr = ["slide","slideup","slidedown","pop","fade","flip"];
$.mobile.changePage(renderedPage, {
  transition: $.inArray(transition,transitionArr) == -1 ? transition : "slide",
  reverse:reverse
});
```

However, i was unable to find an array or object in the core that directly referenced these transitions in a way that we could use to dynamically build this array.

Comment: +1 for $.inArray, but why are you looking up "reverse" in the transitionArr? that's just a boolean.

Comment: another issue in your code: $.inArray() returns index of element in array, so the criteria is met when the transition does not exist in the array (i.e. $.inArray() returns -1).

Comment: sry about the reverse check, i don't do any development in jquery mobile and assumed wrong. fixed. As far as the $.inArray returning -1, -1 is a false-y value, so if it comes up as -1 it will default to "slide". If you want a more exact check you can use !== -1

Comment: This is wrong, any number value in js is assumed "true" unless it is equal to "0". see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tasba/

Comment: sorry, you are correct of course. I'm not sure where i got that from.